# Why does an if function doesn't run prompt again with numbers?

Tags: javascript, function, loops, if-statement, return

The last function is supposed to run again when user does not write any input and presses enter. The first and the second functions work fine : without any valid input, the function runs the right prompt. What is it that I'm missing? Is it because the last if-statements refer to intengers?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta name="author" content="Yann">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Äventyret</title>
    </head>
<html>
<head>
<script src="spel8.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body> 
</html>
```

```
function firstQuestion(){
    var string = prompt("Welcome to the port!\nDo you want to come on board?").toLowerCase();

    if (string === "yes"){
        alert("Interesting!");
        secondQuestion();
        return;
    }
    else if (string === "no"){
        alert("Goodbye!");
        return;
    }
    else {
        alert("Answer with \"yes\" or \"no\".");
    }
    firstQuestion();  
}

firstQuestion();


function secondQuestion() {
  var str = prompt("Have you ever sailed?").toLowerCase();

    if (str === "yes") {
        alert("Great!\nI still have a question for you.");
        thirdQuestion();
        return;
    }
    else if (str === "no"){
        alert("I need experienced sailors!");
        return;
    }
   secondQuestion(); 
}

function thirdQuestion () {
    var string = prompt("How old are you?");

    if (string < 14){
        alert("You're too young!\nGo home!");
        return;
    }
    else if (string >= 14){
        alert("Welcome on board!");
        return;
    }
    thirdQuestion();
}
```

Comment: Please also add your HTML.

Comment: What would make it repeat again? it is either going to be in if or the else if. There is no check to see if the user entered a number. When you do the comparison it is going to use the string. `console.log("" < 14, "">=14);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no chance in the third function for the self-call to `thirdQuestion` to be hit because the `if` and `else if` conditions cover all scenarios. If `string < 14` is not `true`, then its exact opposite `string >= 14` will always be true.

I think you want something more like this:

```
function thirdQuestion () {
    var string = prompt("How old are you?");
    var age = parseFloat(string);

    if (!string || isNaN(age)) {
        return thirdQuestion();
    }

    if (string < 14) {
        alert("You're too young!\nGo home!");
        return;
    }

    alert("Welcome on board!");
}
```

Notice that we convert the input string to a number with `parseFloat`; JavaScript *can* compare strings and numbers, but you might get unexpected results. The code also checks if the string could be successfully parsed as a number with `isNaN` (is not a number).

Comment: Should add another `if` or do I need to edit the existings `if` and `else if`?

Comment: There are lots of ways to structure your conditional code; it largely depends on your personal preferences. The important part is just that you cover all the right cases. Some people prefer `if/else if/else` and some prefer early returns so they can avoid the elses.

Comment: I understand, it's very clear. Thank you for precisely answering my question.

Comment: But why do I need to `return thirdQuestion();` straight after the first `if`?
Both first functions return at their ends, don't they?

Comment: `thirdQuestion` returns, but the return there is just to prevent the first invoking of `thirdQuestion` from continuing. You can use `if/else` instead if preferred so you don't have multiple returns.

Answer (score 0):

First, if we reorganize your code and simplify it, it become much easier to manage. You should not have a function for each question because all the functions essentially do the same thing (check for the right answer, wrong answer, or no answer). Only the questions change, so keep those separate from the functions and use an Array with an index to keep track of which question is being asked:

```js
const questions = [
  "Welcome to the port!\nDo you want to come on board?",
  "Have you ever sailed?",
  "How old are you?"
];

let num = 0; // Keep track of which question is current

function ask(){
  // Make sure we don't ask questions after asking them all
  if(num >= questions.length) {
    return; // Out of questions    
  }

  // Ask the appropriate question and don't name a variable
  // "string" as it gets confusing.
  var answer = prompt(questions[num]).toLowerCase();

  // You don't need or want return statements in this code.
  // Just let the logic dictate the flow through the function
  
  // Determine which answer to check against
  if(num === 2) {
    if (answer > 14){
      alert("Interesting!");
      num++
      ask();
    } else if (answer < 14){
      alert("Goodbye!");
    } else {
      alert("Answer with a number.");
      ask();
    }
    return
  }
  
  if (answer === "yes"){
    alert("Interesting!");
    num++
    ask();
  } else if (answer === "no"){
    alert("Goodbye!");
  } else {
    alert("Answer with \"yes\" or \"no\".");
    ask();
  }
}

ask();
```